# htaccess add trailing slash if there isn't one

Tags: php, .htaccess, trailing-slash

Below is my current htaccess file. It's set up to allow for no extensions and to 301.php and .htm to no extension.

I also need to add trailing slashes whenever there isn't one. There are plenty of topics on here answering that question but I can't seem to add it without messing something else up.

```
RewriteEngine On


# check to see if the request is for a PHP file and rewite to no extension:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]


# redirect PHP or HTM to no extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.(php|htm?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect PHP or HTM to no extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.(php|html?) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [L,R=301]

## Adding a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]    

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file and rewite to no extension:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for that but the page ends up getting stuck in a loop

Comment: There is loop in these rules. Do you have other rules also? Check your page in Chrome dev tool and see what redirects you get.